# pthread works fine only if the number of threads is small

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I am trying to encrypt a BMP image, pixel by pixel, and I use pthread to encrypt them in parallel.

My code is kinda like this:

```
struct arg_struct {
    int arg1;
    int arg2;
    ...
};

void* print_message(void* arguments) {
    struct arg_struct* args = (struct arg_struct*)arguments;

    //Encryption...

    // exit from current thread
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void multiThreadExample() {
    cout << "Start..." << endl;
    const int NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 50000; // number of pixels
    pthread_t thread[NUMBER_OF_THREADS];
    arg_struct arg[NUMBER_OF_THREADS];
    for (int i=0;i<NUMBER_OF_THREADS;i++) {
        arg[i].arg1 = i;
        arg[i].arg2 = ... // give values to arguments in arg_struct
        pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, print_message, static_cast<void*>(&arg[i]));
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_THREADS; i++) {
        pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);
    }

    cout << "Complete..." << endl;

    //streaming results to file using filebuf
}

int main() {

    multiThreadExample();

    return 0;
}
```

It works fine if the image is as small as 3*3.

If the image gets bigger, such as 240*164, the program freezes **AFTER** printing out "Complete..."

After several minutes, it says `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

I'm not sure what makes the program freeze after the most heavy part (encryption) has already completed. Is it because such many threads have already occupied all my memory space? It occupied more than 10G at maximum during running.

---

Actually I have tried to do this **WITHOUT** multithreading, and the program still freezes.

Comment: You need to check that `pthread_create` succeeds.  50000 pthreads is a ton, and you can't join on threads that didn't get created successfully.

Comment: I think `join` function should be successful, maybe? Because if it is not successful, `cout << "Complete..." << endl;` should not be executed.

Comment: @TaihouKai -- Instead of guessing, check the return codes for those functions that will report errors on failure.

Comment: I will have a try and edit my question after that. Thank you!

Comment: What is `print_message` doing?  It creates output of some kind that gets stored somewhere.  Where is that write happening?  It is possible you're writing out of bounds somewhere (corrupting the stack).

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm It is basically encrypting a single pixel. The actual code is quite long so I am not presenting it here.

Comment: _I have tried to do this without multithreading_ That's a good test, and shows that the problem is now in the multithreading code shown in your question but lies elsewhere.  You should use your debugger to ascertain where in the code it is getting stuck, then update the question with the relevant findings so that we can see a [mre].

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I will try to locate where it gets stuck. Thank you!

Comment: I see *no synchronization* and *no error handling*. I smell a race condition or bug due to some undiscovered/unhandled failure. And why on earth would you *ever* want to create 50K threads?? You'll kill all performance in scheduling and synchronization overhead.

Comment: Why use raw pthreads in C++? We have `std::thread` and friends.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Actually I just searched "multithreading c++" in google and picked one of the two I discovered. Is `std::thread` better than pthread?

Comment: @TaihouKai It has "being cross platform" going for it..

Comment: Googling two words then randomly picking one of two results is.... _not_ how to make architectural decisions in computer programming. **Study** your options.

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 -- *Study your options* -- And especially for a topic as advanced as multithreaded programming.

Answer (score 9):

50000 threads is insane. You are most likely running out of memory to allocate stacks for the threads. In general, to get the most out of your CPU through parallelism you only need as many threads as there are CPU cores - that is the limit on the amount of actual concurrency you can get in the hardware. Any more threads, and you are just using up resources for the overhead of thread creation and context switches.

Instead, create a pool of threads equal to the number of cores you have, and break your image up into chunks, and schedule those onto the threads you created.

Comment: With hyperthreading, the limit is 2*CPU cores, and some exotic chips can manage even more threads/core. But that still gets you nowhere near 50.000.

Comment: When I try to encrypt the whole image (~40000 pixel large) without multithreading, the program still freezes. I am thinking whether it is because I didn't get some memory allocated back during ~40000 iteration in that for loop and thus run out of memory. I am so sorry I forget to mention this in my question.

Comment: @TaihouKai Sounds like time to a) add error handling. b) use your debugger. c) use tools like "thread sanitizer" and "address sanitizer".

Comment: @TaihouKai Or d) ask a new question where you show some more code ;)

Comment: @TaihouKai and e) turn your compiler warnings waaay up and turn warnings into errors.

Comment: Will do. Thank you guys.